# Laptop adapter + DC buck/boost converter or buck convereter only?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, boost

I have an old laptop adapter, with 19 V - 4.74 A DC output ratings. Suppose I need to draw 3 A @ 11.1 V for one of my circuits. I have been doing some research about dc-dc converters and have some questions on my mind.

As far as I understood, I will either buy a dc-dc step down(buck) converter and let it convert 19 V to 11.1 V. Then it will do the job(right?).

However, another option is to buy a more sophisticated one, like [this](https://usa.banggood.com/D3806-NC-DC-6A-10V-40V-to-38V-Constant-Current-Power-Supply-Step-Down-Module-Voltage-Ammeter-p-1059235.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN) one. (I think giving a link to product will be easier than explain it.)

Now, I read that these buck+boost converters are working with the principle of boosting any input voltage to high DC and then lowering it to the desired(set by user) DC voltage.

My question is, if I plan to draw 3-4 Amps constantly, will this boosting/bucking(?) be too inefficient? I mean, would using a single buck converter be more suitable for such operation? Or there will not be any difference?

Thanks.

Comment: A link to a bona fide PDF data sheet of a product made by a reputable manufacturer and sourced through a reputable dealer is what is required. Bang-good (or bad) or amazon or peebay or aliexpress just don't cut the mustard in my opinion.

Comment: First, your link is to a buck regulator.  Buck only, no boost.  Second, the efficiency of most switching regulators increases with output current.  That is because as the output power increases, the constant power required to run the regulator circuits at any output become a smaller and smaller percentage of the total power through the device.  My vote:  a straightforward non-isolated buck regulator rated for 50% more than your max anticipated output current.

Comment: @AnalogKid I realized after your comment that they did not mention in the title that it is boost+buck, however it is. You can see it in 5th picture of the product. I also watched reviews of it, and it can boost voltage also. Your comment about efficiency is something I did not know, thanks for that.

Comment: @Andyaka you are right about the quality(about documents etc.) of the product linked. But it was more of a general question about comparison of buck+boost and buck only regulators.

Comment: It may be cheaper to just get a cheap switching lab supply, and set it for 11.1V.  It won't be any less reliable than a single-board supply from the same source, and shouldn't be much more expensive.

Comment: @TimWescott "less reliable than a single-board supply from the same source" can you ellaborate this sentence a bit?

Comment: Bangood = unreliable.  Cheap switching lab supply = unreliable.

Comment: @muyustan I might first open up the existing 19 V laptop adapter and see if I could modify the existing circuit to achieve my goals. It's not unlikely that there is a method available without all this extra gnashing of teeth over a separate DC-DC converter. Just a thought to consider.

Comment: @jonk interesting, what would happen to the output current capability of the adapter if I modified it let's say to 10 volts from 19 volts? Same, double?

Comment: @muyustan Hard to say without knowing anything about what I might find when I open it up. I was just saying what I would probably ***do*** first, to investigate. Not saying what my crystal ball says I'd ***find*** in that hypothetical future. Only you can fix my crystal ball. ;)

Answer (score 3):

A simple buck converter should be more than sufficient for your needs. You can try making one yourself with an [MC34063](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF) + external switching FET or an [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf?ts=1590937945366). Modules for both of those are available online as well.

A single buck converter will, in most cases, be more efficient than a buck/boost converter. The latter generally finds applications when you're drawing power from a battery, where the input voltage can vary over a range. Since you're using a laptop adapter, you can expect a steady supply voltage and use a buck converter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer but your mc34063 link says that it is able to handle currents up to 1.5 A only.

Comment: I mentioned that you should use an external FET for switching higher currents.

Comment: There are plenty of circuits around for using the MC34063 as a switching controller with external transistors.  I wouldn't recommend a switching supply is a first circuit for beginners, though.